# Aligning text in a button

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

I need to make buttons with icons on the left and I found a great example on here about it. But no matter how much I edit it, the text inside won't align vertically. I'm using Bootstrap 4, by the way. Someone help?

Here's the original [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mr6nt5no/4/).

And here's the code:

```css
.btn {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0.7em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background: #42473d;
  padding: 1em 0.5em;
  color: #fff;
}

.btn-primary:before {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  font-size: 2em;
  width: (18em / 14);
  float: left;
  margin: -0.5em -0.2em;
  padding: 0.3em 0.6em;
  background-color: #292c26;
  content: "\f230";
}
.btn-secondary:before {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  font-size: 2em;
  width: (25em / 14);
  float: left;
  margin: -0.5em -0.2em;
  padding: 0.3em 0.6em;
  background-color: #292c26;
  content: "\f179";
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<button class="btn btn-block rounded-0">
    View Using Facebook
</button>
<button class="btn btn-block rounded-0">
    View Using Facebook
</button>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use chrome tools inspector you can see you added padding correctly but the issue is with the text itself. Add a line-height of initial/normal and it fixes the problem.

```
.btn {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 0.7em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background: #42473d;
    padding: 1em 0.5em;
    color: #fff;
    line-height: initial;
}
```

Comment: `line-height: initial;` Won't work in IE, you should use  `line-height: normal` instead.

Comment: Yup, it fixes up the alignment for that size. But what if I want to make the buttons wider? if I touch the padding on the .btn, the icon background doesn't scale with it: https://jsfiddle.net/ck6way06/1/

Comment: Your question was only about the text alignment. Assuming you do want the buttons wider but they will fixed, you'll have to adjust the css the match what you want; like you did before on the smaller button. Your width css is also invalid, it needs calc if you want to perform maths in css `width: calc(18em/14)`.

Comment: I found a solution! For anyone who might need it later! Just wrap the text inside a <span> and add line-height to span according to your button height. And it'll fix the problem! Thanks Jason, your answer did help! Checking it as a correct one right away!

Answer (score 0):

I hope it will solve your issue.

```css
.btn {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0.7em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background: #42473d;
  padding: 1em 0.5em;
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  height: 40px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.btn:before {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  font-size: 1.5em;
  float: left;
  padding: 4px 10px;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  background-color: #292c26;
  content: "\f230";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<button class="btn btn-block rounded-0">
    View Using Facebook
</button>
<button class="btn btn-block rounded-0">
    View Using Facebook
</button>
```